# rails post params empty

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, post

I'm trying to pass parameters into a rails app and I can't seem to figure out why my form works one way, but not the other.

**Working Solution**

```
<form action="/users/alerts_setting" method="post" id="alerts_setting_form">
  <% alerts.each do |alert| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= alert.name %></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" <%#= "checked" if alert.visible == true -%> name="<%= alert.id %>" id="<%= alert.id %>" value="visible" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" <%#= "checked" if alert.subscribed == true -%> name="<%= alert.id %>" id="<%= alert.id %>" value="subscribed" /></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <input onclick="<%= spinner_js('alert_settings_spinner')-%>" type="submit" value="Save"><%= spinner('alert_settings_spinner') -%>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
```

Passes the following parameters successfully (taken from development.log)

```
Started POST "/users/alerts_setting" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-27 02:52:11 -0700
Processing by UsersController#alerts_setting as HTML
  Parameters: {"17"=>"visible"}
```

Now if I take a similar approach, but make the checkbox clickable, on POST the parameters don't get passed

**Non-working Solution**

```
<form action="/users/alerts_setting" method="post" id="alerts_setting_form">
  <input onclick="Form.remote_submit($('alerts_setting_form'));" type="checkbox" <%#= "checked" if alert.visible == true -%> name="<%= alert.id %>" id="<%= alert.id %>" value="visible" />
</form>
```

Produces the following in my development.log

```
Started POST "/users/alerts_setting" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-27 02:56:48 -0700
Processing by UsersController#alerts_setting as JS
```

The only thing obvious that I see is that in one case its processing it as HTML and in the other case its processing it JS

Comment: Instead of specifying `onclick` in the DOM element, can you try the following? <script type='text/javascript>$('#alerts_setting_form input:checkbox').click(function(){ $('#alerts_setting_form').ajaxSubmit(); });</script>

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. It can't seem to access the element the error in the console was "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: $ is a Jquery implementation. I think jquery needs to be loaded first prior to this script. Do it like this then:  `<script type='text/javascript>$(function(){ $('#alerts_setting_form input:checkbox').click(function(){ $('#alerts_setting_form').ajaxSubmit(); });})</script>` After that remove the onclick for each checkbox. Hope that works.